# having problems with my update it has no errors but not updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
  public void Updateemployee(employeeView model)
        {
            using (var emprep = new employeeRepository())
            {
                var employee= new employee();


                if (emp != null)
                {

                   emp.employee_Name = model.employee_Name;
                    emp.employee_Address = model.employee_Address;
                    emp.Email = model.Email;
                    emp.Contact_No = model.Contact_No;
                    emp.Update(emp);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of your problem in the question. What are you trying to do, and what exactly is going wrong? Also, please tag your question with the language you're using - it'll help experts who could help you find your question.

Comment: where is your `emp` variable? you are declaring `employee` and then working on `emp`?

Comment: What is your programming language?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to get by id.

```
public void Updateemployee(employeeView model)
    {
        using (var emprep = new employeeRepository())
        {
            var employee= new employee();


            if (emp != null)
            {
                //here  
                `enter code here`emp=emprep.GetById(model.emp_Id);

                emp.employee_Name = model.employee_Name;
                emp.employee_Address = model.employee_Address;
                emp.Email = model.Email;
                emp.Contact_No = model.Contact_No;
                emp.Update(emp);
            }
        }
    }
```